# Is there any decent git repository manager that's downloadable?

Tags: git, version-control, hosting

I want to host git repos on my server, but still have a nice tool to manage them, such as [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) or Assembla.

Does anyone know of a similar tool which is downloadable (Other than Assembla private)? Security and reliability concerns won't allow for hosted solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [**GitBlit**](http://gitblit.com/). It is incredibly easy to install and to use compared to GitLab or Gitorious.

It took me few minutes to deploy it on a local Tomcat and create my first repository.
In parallel, I'm still fighting (for days) with GitLab (on RH6.4 box without internet access)

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you. These three are the kind of projects I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

**[Gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)** is far more advanced than gitosis, and is quite easy to install, directly from your workstation (based on ssh communication with your Git repository server).

**It is only for managing complex ACLs though**, meaning it has no web front-end, even though you can quickly interface it with GitWeb (which comes with Git).
It also have no integration with Basecamp, Campfire (, ... and so on).

Comment: Thanks, Gitolite looks really powerful.
I didn't explicitly write that before, but having a usable front-end is a huge plus. Isn't there any repo manager with a front end?

Comment: @Ronny: GitWeb is a good start, but for all the other git web interfaces, look here: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#Web_Interface

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way)?

Comment: Not yet, but I'll give it a try. Thanks!